# How to check for memory leaks in JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

In my JNI program, I use

```
new
delete
env->NewGlobalRef
env->DeleteGlobalRef
jvm->AttachCurrentThread
jvm->DetachCurrentThread
```

What is a good way to check for memory leaks rigorously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that every `new`, `env->NewGlobalRef` and `jvm->AttachCurrentThread` is in the constructor of an object which calls the matching deallocation function in its destructor.

This is a technique called [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII), which is vital to writing any correct program in C++.

Answer (score 0):

- First try to use [smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).
- As Mankarse pointed out, try to use the RAII idiom whenever possible to create and delete your global references.
- Use as less global rferences as possible
- Free local references when constructing them in a loop

Take a look at [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/refs.html) for managing references.

Do you already know that your native code is leaking memory?

Comment: No, I do not know if it's leaking memory. I just feel insecure without valgrind.